# write a std::string to comparable *time* parser which may fail

Tags: c++, c++11, time-t

I know that size_t is unsigned and hence negative values are not allowed, time_t is to the best of my knowledge signed, so I am allowed to assign -1 to a size_t. However, for time_t I'm not entirely sure. If I follow the definition through the header files I end up here:

```cpp
typedef __time_t time_t;
```

, then here:

```cpp
__STD_TYPE __TIME_T_TYPE __time_t;  /* Seconds since the Epoch.  */
```

and finally

```cpp
#define __TIME_T_TYPE       __SYSCALL_SLONG_TYPE
```

I'm not too sure what a **__SYSCALL_SLONG_TYPE** is, but I guess it is a **signed long**. Unfortunately, even after doing this trace, I can only hope that other c++11 platforms have the same implementation. I'm still not sure that this will be legal and well-defined for all of them:

```cpp
size_t foo = -1;
```

Of course it makes sense to make a time_t signed, since one can have negative time offsets, for example to model time zones. But on the other hand it makes sense to have it unsigned, because there are a lot of seconds to count after 1970. So common sense goes both ways :) Googling on time_t returned this:

"For historical reasons, it is generally implemented as an integral value representing the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC (i.e., a unix timestamp). Although libraries may implement this type using alternative time representations."

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/

and on the same page: "Portable programs should not use values of this type directly, but always rely on calls to elements of the standard library to translate them to portable types."

So time_t is not at all well-defined on all systems, however, time() returns a time_t: so I wouldn't be the first to export it in an interface. What other type should I use?

I'm asking for these two reasons:

- **Speed:** Using a struct, like **struct tm** is slow, as it has more bytes and hence copying it or comparing it with another struct tm will be slower than doing the same with a long.
- **Ordering:** I want to have a fast data type for dates, which allows me to do a < b to figure out which of the dates a and b comes first.

**Question:** Since time_t is not a well-defined time representation on all platforms, what kind of data type that is (1) fast and (2) comparable can I use that is portable?

For example, regarding the ordering of time_t:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    struct tm tm_a, tm_b;
    memset(&tm_a, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(&tm_b, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    if(strptime("2014-01-01 12:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s", &tm_a) && strptime("2014-01-01 11:59:59", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s", &tm_b)) {
        if(mktime(&tm_a) > mktime(&tm_b)) std::cout << "time_t ordering OK." << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "time_t ordering tainted" << std::endl;
    } else std::cout << "failed to parse time" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Will time_t be *untainted* on all platforms?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I will elaborate a bit, apologies for not being clear the fist time. One moment.

Comment: Would this suit as an acceptable question?

Comment: I also removed the part about error handling, It is a second question about coding style, and it confuses the original question. Sorry for being a scatter brain :) I hope I fixed it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(time_t)(-1)` already means "this is not a valid time", regardless of what `time_t` actually is. The standard function [`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) returns this value on error, so can you.

The C and C++ standards say nothing about encoding of time in `time_t`. The standard function `difftime` computes time difference in seconds, as a `double`, between two times represented as `time_t`, and that's the only blessed way to order `time_t` values chronologically. However, the POSIX standard specifies that `time_t` is the time in seconds, so on a POSIX system it is OK to compare `time_t` directly with `<`.

Note that both C and POSIX permit `time_t` to be any arithmetic type (not just integral).

Comment: You are entirely right, thank you for this answer. Although, on my error of not being clear from the beginning, the real question would (also) be "is the ordering of a time_t type chronological according to the < operator".

Comment: Basically, I'm wondering how **cross platform** different (mathematical) properties of a time_t are, like ordering and using negative values.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to re-interpreter my question and add the difftime(). That is a very valid solution for my ordering problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a time representation which is guaranteed to be portable between different platforms, you need to use or create a library which takes care of the differences between the platforms you use.

For example [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time.html), there you can select any representation it supports. You can even use [seconds elapsed since epoch](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.seconds_since_epoch) in a way which is platform independent (on all platforms supported by boost).

Comment: I moved the accept to difftime, since it is a c++/c solution, instead of an external library solution. Thank you for your valid suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

I have become addicted to `optional` (via boost, or roll your own based off C++1y tr working paper).

`optional<foo>` is either a `foo` or a `nullopt`.  You access the `foo` via dereerence, but the data is stored within the `optional` via a union.  My lazy implememtation uses a pointer for the 'is it a `foo` or not" as that makes debugging trivial.

It both communicates failure better than flag values, and replaces a bunch of pointer-based flagging in code I write.